# ERROR controller.provisioning Could not schedule pod, incompatible with provisioner "default", incompatible requirements, key karpenter.sh/provisioner

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks, karpenter

I read through the karpenter document at https://karpenter.sh/v0.16.1/getting-started/getting-started-with-terraform/#install-karpenter-helm-chart. I followed instructions step by step. I got errors at the end.

kubectl logs -f -n karpenter -l app.kubernetes.io/name=karpenter -c controller

DEBUG   controller.provisioning Relaxing soft constraints for pod since it previously failed to schedule, removing: spec.topologySpreadConstraints = {"maxSkew":1,"topologyKey":"topology.kubernetes.io/zone","whenUnsatisfiable":"ScheduleAnyway","labelSelector":{"matchLabels":{"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"karpenter","app.kubernetes.io/name":"karpenter"}}} {"commit": "b157d45", "pod": "karpenter/karpenter-5755bb5b54-rh65t"}
2022-09-10T00:13:13.122Z

ERROR   controller.provisioning Could not schedule pod, incompatible with provisioner "default", incompatible requirements, key karpenter.sh/provisioner-name, karpenter.sh/provisioner-name DoesNotExist not in karpenter.sh/provisioner-name In [default] {"commit": "b157d45", "pod": "karpenter/karpenter-5755bb5b54-rh65t"}

Below is the source code:

```
cat main.tf
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.0"

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }
    helm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/helm"
      version = "~> 2.5"
    }
    kubectl = {
      source  = "gavinbunney/kubectl"
      version = "~> 1.14"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

locals {
  cluster_name = "karpenter-demo"

  # Used to determine correct partition (i.e. - `aws`, `aws-gov`, `aws-cn`, etc.)
  partition = data.aws_partition.current.partition
}

data "aws_partition" "current" {}

module "vpc" {
  # https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws/latest
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "3.14.4"

  name = local.cluster_name
  cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"

  azs             = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c"]
  private_subnets = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24", "10.0.3.0/24"]
  public_subnets  = ["10.0.101.0/24", "10.0.102.0/24", "10.0.103.0/24"]

  enable_nat_gateway     = true
  single_nat_gateway     = true
  one_nat_gateway_per_az = false

  public_subnet_tags = {
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/${local.cluster_name}" = "shared"
    "kubernetes.io/role/elb"                      = 1
  }

  private_subnet_tags = {
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/${local.cluster_name}" = "shared"
    "kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb"             = 1
  }
}

module "eks" {
  # https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/latest
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "18.29.0"

  cluster_name    = local.cluster_name
  cluster_version = "1.22"

  vpc_id     = module.vpc.vpc_id
  subnet_ids = module.vpc.private_subnets

  # Required for Karpenter role below
  enable_irsa = true

  node_security_group_additional_rules = {
    ingress_nodes_karpenter_port = {
      description                   = "Cluster API to Node group for Karpenter webhook"
      protocol                      = "tcp"
      from_port                     = 8443
      to_port                       = 8443
      type                          = "ingress"
      source_cluster_security_group = true
    }
  }

  node_security_group_tags = {
    # NOTE - if creating multiple security groups with this module, only tag the
    # security group that Karpenter should utilize with the following tag
    # (i.e. - at most, only one security group should have this tag in your account)
    "karpenter.sh/discovery/${local.cluster_name}" = local.cluster_name
  }

  # Only need one node to get Karpenter up and running.
  # This ensures core services such as VPC CNI, CoreDNS, etc. are up and running
  # so that Karpenter can be deployed and start managing compute capacity as required
  eks_managed_node_groups = {
    initial = {
      instance_types = ["m5.large"]
      # Not required nor used - avoid tagging two security groups with same tag as well
      create_security_group = false

      min_size     = 1
      max_size     = 1
      desired_size = 1

      iam_role_additional_policies = [
        "arn:${local.partition}:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore", # Required by Karpenter
        "arn:${local.partition}:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy",
        "arn:${local.partition}:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly", #for access to ECR images
        "arn:${local.partition}:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy"
      ]

      tags = {
        # This will tag the launch template created for use by Karpenter
        "karpenter.sh/discovery/${local.cluster_name}" = local.cluster_name
      }
    }
  }
}

#The EKS module creates an IAM role for the EKS managed node group nodes. We’ll use that for Karpenter.
#We need to create an instance profile we can reference.
#Karpenter can use this instance profile to launch new EC2 instances and those instances will be able to connect to your cluster.
resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "karpenter" {
  name = "KarpenterNodeInstanceProfile-${local.cluster_name}"
  role = module.eks.eks_managed_node_groups["initial"].iam_role_name
}

#Create the KarpenterController IAM Role
#Karpenter requires permissions like launching instances, which means it needs an IAM role that grants it access. The config
#below will create an AWS IAM Role, attach a policy, and authorize the Service Account to assume the role using IRSA. We will
#create the ServiceAccount and connect it to this role during the Helm chart install.

module "karpenter_irsa" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/iam/aws//modules/iam-role-for-service-accounts-eks"
  version = "5.3.3"

  role_name                          = "karpenter-controller-${local.cluster_name}"
  attach_karpenter_controller_policy = true

  karpenter_tag_key               = "karpenter.sh/discovery/${local.cluster_name}"
  karpenter_controller_cluster_id = module.eks.cluster_id
  karpenter_controller_node_iam_role_arns = [
    module.eks.eks_managed_node_groups["initial"].iam_role_arn
  ]

  oidc_providers = {
    ex = {
      provider_arn               = module.eks.oidc_provider_arn
      namespace_service_accounts = ["karpenter:karpenter"]
    }
  }
}

#Install Karpenter Helm Chart
#Use helm to deploy Karpenter to the cluster. We are going to use the helm_release Terraform resource to do the deploy and pass in the
#cluster details and IAM role Karpenter needs to assume.
provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host                   = module.eks.cluster_endpoint
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.eks.cluster_certificate_authority_data)

    exec {
      api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1"
      command     = "aws"
      args        = ["eks", "get-token", "--cluster-name", local.cluster_name]
    }
  }
}

resource "helm_release" "karpenter" {
  namespace        = "karpenter"
  create_namespace = true

  name       = "karpenter"
  repository = "https://charts.karpenter.sh"
  chart      = "karpenter"
  version    = "v0.16.1"

  set {
    name  = "serviceAccount.annotations.eks\\.amazonaws\\.com/role-arn"
    value = module.karpenter_irsa.iam_role_arn
  }

  set {
    name  = "clusterName"
    value = module.eks.cluster_id
  }

  set {
    name  = "clusterEndpoint"
    value = module.eks.cluster_endpoint
  }

  set {
    name  = "aws.defaultInstanceProfile"
    value = aws_iam_instance_profile.karpenter.name
  }
}

#Provisioner
#Create a default provisioner using the command below. This provisioner configures instances to connect to your cluster’s endpoint and
#discovers resources like subnets and security groups using the cluster’s name.
#This provisioner will create capacity as long as the sum of all created capacity is less than the specified limit.
provider "kubectl" {
  apply_retry_count      = 5
  host                   = module.eks.cluster_endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.eks.cluster_certificate_authority_data)
  load_config_file       = false

  exec {
    api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1"
    command     = "aws"
    args        = ["eks", "get-token", "--cluster-name", module.eks.cluster_id]
  }
}

resource "kubectl_manifest" "karpenter_provisioner" {
  yaml_body = <<-YAML
  apiVersion: karpenter.sh/v1alpha5
  kind: Provisioner
  metadata:
    name: default
  spec:
    requirements:
      - key: karpenter.sh/capacity-type
        operator: In
        values: ["spot"]
    limits:
      resources:
        cpu: 1000
    provider:
      subnetSelector:
        Name: "*private*"
      securityGroupSelector:
        karpenter.sh/discovery/${module.eks.cluster_id}: ${module.eks.cluster_id}
      tags:
        karpenter.sh/discovery/${module.eks.cluster_id}: ${module.eks.cluster_id}
    ttlSecondsAfterEmpty: 30
  YAML

  depends_on = [
    helm_release.karpenter
  ]
}

cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: inflate
spec:
  replicas: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: inflate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: inflate
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
      containers:
        - name: inflate
          image: public.ecr.aws/eks-distro/kubernetes/pause:3.2
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 1
EOF
```

kubectl scale deployment inflate --replicas 5

kubectl logs -f -n karpenter -l app.kubernetes.io/name=karpenter -c controller

DEBUG   controller.provisioning Relaxing soft constraints for pod since it previously failed to schedule, removing: spec.topologySpreadConstraints = {"maxSkew":1,"topologyKey":"topology.kubernetes.io/zone","whenUnsatisfiable":"ScheduleAnyway","labelSelector":{"matchLabels":{"app.kubernetes.io/instance":"karpenter","app.kubernetes.io/name":"karpenter"}}} {"commit": "b157d45", "pod": "karpenter/karpenter-5755bb5b54-rh65t"}
2022-09-10T00:13:13.122Z

ERROR   controller.provisioning Could not schedule pod, incompatible with provisioner "default", incompatible requirements, key karpenter.sh/provisioner-name, karpenter.sh/provisioner-name DoesNotExist not in karpenter.sh/provisioner-name In [default] {"commit": "b157d45", "pod": "karpenter/karpenter-5755bb5b54-rh65t"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive this is due to the pod topology defined in the Karpenter deployment here:

https://github.com/aws/karpenter/blob/main/charts/karpenter/values.yaml#L73-L77

, you can read further on what pod topologySpreadConstraints does here:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/topology-spread-constraints/

If you increase the desired_size to 2 which matches the default deployment replicas above, that should resove the error.